# Should HTTPS be used for all calls involving authorization

Tags: https

It's common to use HTTPS for authentication, so the authentication details from client cannot be sniffed. However once the user is logged in then subsequent calls to a web app passing some sort of auth id which then the web app will then use to authorise with, should that not also be HTTPS? How is this done in things like Facebook?  Seems easier to make all traffic HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer by Jeff Atwood:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/should-all-web-traffic-be-encrypted.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the server can handle it, I'd go a step further and use SSL for **everything**, no matter if users are logged in or not.

This has the advantage that an eavesdropper doesn't even know if the user is accessing your site/app as a guest or as an authenticated user. It also saves you from having to decide when to use SSL and when not.